# How to get StrikeThrough on a String ? Not a TextView, EditText or a View. But like String a = "my text" and then pass it to SQLite as a String

Tags: java, android

I have this method which works fine for an EditText or a view.

```
public SpannableString strikeThrough(String txt){

    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(txt);
    StrikethroughSpan strikethroughSpan = new StrikethroughSpan();
    spannableString.setSpan(strikethroughSpan,0, txt.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return spannableString;

}

 EditText etChecklistItem = checklistView.findViewById(R.id.et_checklist_item);
 etChecklistItem.setText(strikeThrough(etChecklistItem.getText().toString()));
```

But my problem is after that, the text doesn't have StrikeThrough.

```
 StringBuilder stringBuilderItem = new StringBuilder();
            for( String list : itemslist) {
                stringBuilderItem.append(list);
                stringBuilderItem.append("\n");
            }

  String text = stringBuilderItem.toString();
  strikeThrough(text);
 dbHelper.insertChecklist(text);
```

When I get the data in RecyclerView, it would not be in Strikethrough.

Comment: can share some sample image that you are excepting to have like that?

Comment: I want like this image. https://ibb.co/gmNnZtr

Comment: you want background like blue also?

Comment: No just the line, but If you could tell how also do to the background the better.

Comment: @Omer123 you can use setPaintFlags like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72787069/16177121)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing a strike-through string inside the array, Create a `class` having two members a `String` and a `boolean`, and make the boolean `true` for the string you want to strike through.

```java
class Message {
    private String str;
    private boolean strike;

    public Message (String str, boolean strike) {
        this.str = str;
        this.strike = strike;
    }
    
    // getters and setters
}
```

and make string strike through when you're showing it on the screen

```java
ArrayList<Message> arr = new ArrayList<>();
for (Message msg: arr) {
    if (arr.getStrike()) {
        // make string strikethrough
    } else {
        // keep as it is
    }
}
```

---

### To strike through a string in TextView

- **Method 1**

```java
textView.setText("I want like that")
textView.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

- **Method 2:** If you want to strike through only a part of the text then use

```java
String str = "I want like that";
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(str);
StrikethroughSpan strikethroughSpan = new StrikethroughSpan();
builder.setSpan(
        strikethroughSpan,
        0, // Start
        4, // End (exclusive)
        Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE // Text changes will not reflect in the strike changing
);
textView.setText(spanBuilder);
```

- **Method 3:** If you want to strike through text in strings.xml

```
<string name="yourName"><strike>I want like that</strike></string>
```

references: [[1]](https://riptutorial.com/android/example/18968/strikethrough-textview)

Comment: Sorry, but it is not working for me. I know how to do it for a view. I want to do it for a String that is generated dynamically from an ArrayList. The String is not available in Xml file. ( String x = "a";)  look, here you can't setPaintFlags for x

Comment: @Omer123 check the updated answer

Comment: Appreciate your answer. I'll fixed inside onViewHolder in the AdapterClass.

Answer (score 1):

Just Checkout this Code

First you need to initialise you edit text or text view

```
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText("Hello World");
    textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

I hope this will help you, if any problem just comment down

Comment: for background just add this line in your xml  android:background="you_color_code_here" remember that choose light color

Comment: Sorry, but it is not working for me. I know how to do it for a view. I want to do it for a String that is generated dynamically from an ArrayList. The String is not available in Xml file. ( String x = "a";)  look, here you can't setPaintFlags for x

Comment: but you might be calling setText method?? after call of arraylist and after that you might be calling setText method

Comment: No, you cant call setText on a String. You only can call setText on a View not just String of text

Comment: ohh I got it what you are trying to do!!...

Comment: Have you got any idea how to fix that?